# How to Update Local Branch to Remote Master on Github?

Tags: git, github, git-merge, branching-and-merging

I just want to have the master changes on my branch, but not my branch changes to be merged with master yet. I have some unfinished work and I want to just get the new code that was pushed onto master on my branch and not have to push my local changes just yet

Comment: Sounds like a simple git pull

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First say `git fetch`. That gives you the latest changes in all branches from the remote, but they are hidden away in the remote tracking branches.

Now if you want to merge the latest state of `master` into your current branch, say `git merge origin/master`. If you are worried that this might override your current uncommitted work, you could `git stash` before merging and `git pop` after merging; however, it would be better to add and commit before merging.

Note that you do *not* need to switch to a local `master` for any of this. Indeed, many people do not need a local `master` at all.

Answer (score 1):

case A)
If you are on master locally:

```
git pull
```

case B)
You are on other branch:

```
git checkout master
git pull
git checkout yourBranch
git merge master
```

Handle conflicts with your pref difftool.

when it's all said and done, open PR from your branch to master. (although you should have a develop branch.)